# How to hide server controls untill angular load custom multi select dropdown

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i am working with asp.net webform and angular.i have few asp.net server side controls in page and i have used a angular multi select dropdown which invoke server side function to get data. so when i am running my application then server side controls comes so fast but later angular multi select display which look odd.

so please see my code and suggest me how to refactor my code to sync the server side and client side UI appear at same time.

### here is bit of my server side code

```
public ActionResult MultiSelectCountry()
        {
            ViewBag.Countries = GetCountries();
            return View();
        }

        [NonAction]
        public JsonResult GetCountries()
        {
            List<Country> oList = new List<Country>()
           {
                new Country {ID=1,Name="United Kingdom"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="United States"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="Italy"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="Germany"},
                new Country {ID=1,Name="India"}
           };
            return Json(oList);
}
```

### here is bit of my client side code

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
          <searchable-multiselect display-attr="Name"
              selected-items="SelectedCountryList" all-items="CountryList"
              add-item="addLanguageToUser(item)" remove-item="removeLanguageFromUser(item)" >
        </searchable-multiselect>
      </div>

    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-bootstrap" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" data-semver="0.13.0"></script>

    <script>
        var _countries =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Countries));

        var app = angular.module('app', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

        var yourApp = yourApp || {};
        yourApp.Settings = yourApp.Settings || {};
        yourApp.Settings.BaseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";
        yourApp.Settings.CountryList = _countries["Data"];
        angular.module("app").value("appSettings", yourApp);
    </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

### app.js code

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, appSettings) {
    $scope.CountryList = appSettings.Settings.CountryList;
    $scope.SelectedCountryList = [];

    $scope.addLanguageToUser = function (country) {
        $scope.SelectedCountryList.push(country)
    };

    $scope.removeLanguageFromUser = function (country) {
        var idx = $scope.SelectedCountryList.indexOf(country);
        $scope.SelectedCountryList.splice(idx, 1);
    };
});

app.directive("searchableMultiselect", function ($timeout, appSettings) {
    return {
        templateUrl: appSettings.Settings.BaseUrl + 'Angular/Directives/searchableMultiselect.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            displayAttr: '@',
            selectedItems: '=',
            allItems: '=',
            readOnly: '=',
            addItem: '&',
            removeItem: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            });

            scope.width = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

            scope.updateSelectedItems = function (obj) {
                var selectedObj;
                for (i = 0; typeof scope.selectedItems !== 'undefined' && i < scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                    if (scope.selectedItems[i][scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() === obj[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase()) {
                        selectedObj = scope.selectedItems[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (typeof selectedObj === 'undefined') {
                    scope.addItem({ item: obj });
                } else {
                    scope.removeItem({ item: selectedObj });
                }
            };

            scope.isItemSelected = function (item) {
                if (typeof scope.selectedItems === 'undefined') return false;

                var tmpItem;
                for (i = 0; i < scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                    tmpItem = scope.selectedItems[i];
                    if (typeof tmpItem !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof tmpItem[scope.displayAttr] !== 'undefined'
                    && typeof item[scope.displayAttr] !== 'undefined'
                    && tmpItem[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() === item[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            };

            scope.commaDelimitedSelected = function () {
                var list = "";
                angular.forEach(scope.selectedItems, function (item, index) {
                    list += item[scope.displayAttr];
                    if (index < scope.selectedItems.length - 1) list += ', ';
                });
                return list.length ? list : "Nothing Selected";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

my request is modify my code in such way as a result server side controls will be visible only when multi select is ready to show. all UI related things should be visible at same time. thanks

Comment: maybe you should consider using `ui-router` or `ngRoute` with `resolve`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like
`<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" ng-show="MainCtrl.CountryList.length>0">` should probably do the trick.

Comment: can't we have a property of scope name isbusy and set isbusy to true when country data come to client side ?

Comment: need one info that can we show/hide element with ng-if instead of ng-show or ng-hide ? if possible please give me little sample code. thanks

Comment: Yes, you could certainly do that. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: suppose i am showing data in div and when loading data then i want to show a overlay over the div when a spinner will display until data is fully loaded at client side. so tell me what approach i should follow. thanks